# One CPU core stuck at 100% doing kernel stuff

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, lock

A few days ago I started experiencing a weird issue - one core was stuck at 100% doing some kernel stuff. This problem is NOT OS specific: it occurs in Windows 7 (including Safe Mode), Ubuntu 12.04 installed on the hard drive and Ubuntu 12.04 on live USB.

What I've tried so far:

- Different OSes
- Disabling hyperthreading (with hyperthreading enabled, only one thread gets locked, not the whole core)
- Resetting BIOS
- Updated BIOS from P03ABJ to P05ABJ
- Re-installed Windows 7

My system:

- Samsung Series 7 Chronos (NP700Z5C-S02UB)
- Core i7-3635QM CPU
- Windows 7 Professional SP1 or Ubuntu 12.04

EDIT: So this is a bit bizarre. I "reset" the laptop and re-installed Win7. After a short while the problem disappeared both in Windows AND Linux. Now, after installing Intel chipset drivers the problem is back again.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: In task manager is there any process that has a high CPU usage?

Comment: No, System Idle is the highest. If I look at Resource Monitor, nothing there either. The only weird thing is a somewhat high number of interrupts (~14 avg).

Comment: Could be a faulty hard drive and the OS is trying to fix over the bad sectors. That would explain why you are having problems with both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: @ConnDarcy would that also apply for Live USB distro?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but it's possible. You could remove the hard drive and then see if there is any change with the Ubuntu Live USB.